# How to compile Cypress TypeScript without running tests

Tags: typescript, cypress, e2e-testing

Our project uses Cypress to run e2e tests. We have 5 different suites that run twice a day, at different times.

My problem is that we can currently introduce compilation problems and we won't find out until we run the e2e tests, which is after we've committed. I would like to be able to build my Cypress TypeScript to make sure it doesn't have any type errors so that we can prevent pushing to main.

[I have not been able to find some configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#Options) that would compile all the TypeScript but would not run the tests. Has anyone been able to achieve such configuration?

Comment: Cant you compile TS regularly? Why you need cypress to do it? If missing some global variables just install the Cypress types

Comment: @RazLuvaton We use cucumber and my (unfounded) concern was that Cypress converts the feature files into JavaScript and I thought I would not be compiling the full code. You are correct though, that I don't need to compile the generated code from cucumber feature files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be as simple as @RazLuvaton mentioned. Just run `tsc` on your own. You can even pass the `--no-emit` if, like me, you just want check types.